# Images won't display when src defined in External CSS - All Browsers

Tags: css, image, external

I'm working on a project for a client that involved using the existing code they have while also transitioning the files into another location. The files being transitioned include images that can't be moved yet, so in an attempt to make the code future proof, I used CSS to define the image src's by embedding them in the "a" tag.

```css
 .iconWriting::before {    content:url("http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/V3/courseFramework/images/icons/writing_standards_resources.png");
 }
 iconWriting {
  width: 32px; 
  height: 32px;
  margin: 1px; 
  border: none; 
  float: right;
  }
```

```html
<a class="iconWriting" href="http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/V3/courseFramework/StartHere/V3_Start_Here-Writing.htm" target="_blank"></a>
```

Unfortunately, the images will only display correctly when the CSS style defining their location is in the Head of the document. I need to be able to house these styles in an External CSS file, but when I move the previously working CSS to the External file, it breaks. Instead of images, I just get the alt text, in all browsers. I tried adding ":before" to the class specification, but this didn't work, either.

Here's a Fiddle of the working code: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gxmqnjy/2/)

Comment: Does anything else break when you move the css to an external file?

Comment: Images don't have a `content` property to affect in this way.

Comment: @JamesHamann No, that's the thing, all of the other styles function perfectly well. :/

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm pretty sure the "content" property is supported for images in CSS3.

Comment: @CodeLyfe Nope. Also, the fiddle doesn't work, even though it has its css in its head.

Comment: `content` can contain image links, images cannot contain `content`. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: @Paulie_D That being said, I'm not targeting the image tag itself with the CSS, but a class belonging to the image. The information you've provided is very helpful, but do you have any idea how I can apply it to get the desired outcome? Should I skip using the img tag all together and just use a div with the background-image property?

Comment: @CodeLyfe Since you have no other content in the `a` links, you can just use the `a`s themselves. Provided you use `::before` or `::after`.

Comment: @MrLister That's bizarre, the JS Fiddle displays for me. Perhaps it has to do with where the images themselves are hosted or maybe their cached for me. Anyway, let me work with what you've suggested, sounds promising.

Comment: @CodeLyfe Oh boy, the fiddle does work in Chrome. I should have checked immediately, sorry. Anyway, it's not supposed to work!

Comment: @MrLister LoL, no harm done. I'm in the process of updating the Fiddle to get this working per your suggestion. Thank you for the help! Do you mind posting your suggestion as an Answer so I can get you credit for it? Also, when using a::before, I can't target the image to specify it's size anymore, can I?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mr Lister for his help with this; the solution is to target the "a" tag when specifying the image src using the "content" property.

```css
/*Weekly Activity Styles*/

 .activityWrapper {
  width: 96%; 
  overflow-x: hidden;"
 }
 
 /*Upper Right Icons*/
 .iconExpand::before  {
  content:url("http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/V2/icon/sm_expand.png");
 }
 .iconAcademic::before {
  content:url("http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/V3/courseFramework/images/icons/academic_research_policy.png");
 }
 .iconWriting::before {
  content:url("http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/V3/courseFramework/images/icons/writing_standards_resources.png");
 }
 .iconExpand, .iconAcademic, .iconWriting {
  width: 32px; 
  height: 32px;
  margin: 1px; 
  border: none; 
  float: right;
  }
 
 /*Dropbox & Waypoint Icons*/
 .iconDropbox {
  content:url("http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/images/Dropbox_small.png");
  border: none;
 }
 .iconWaypoint {
  content:url("http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/images/waypoint_smaller.png");
  border: none;
 }    
 
 .iconWaypointLg {
  content:url("http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/images/Waypoint_image1.png");
  border: none;
 }  

    padding: 15px 20px 5px 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="activityWrapper">
<div class="subParaDisc">

<a target="_new" href="javascript://;" class="iconLink iconExpand" onclick="this.href=document.location"></a>
<a class="iconAcademic" target="_new" href="http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/V3/courseFramework/StartHere/V3_Start_Here-Academic.htm"></a>
 <a class="iconWriting" href="http://wpc.6FDC.edgecastcdn.net/006FDC/UOR_Curriculum/V3/courseFramework/StartHere/V3_Start_Here-Writing.htm" target="_blank"></a>
<h1>
The Icons above only work when the style defining their img content is in the head of the HTML doc.</h1>



</div>
</div>
```

Reference this Fiddle for the sample: https://jsfiddle.net/1gxmqnjy/21/